# What is the role of character || in the variable declaration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example

```
var myVar = myVar || {};
```

or

```
var myVar = myVar || [];
```

What does this statement mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides the default value for `myVar` in case `myVar` evaluates to false.

This can happen when `myVar` is either:

- false
- 0
- empty string
- null
- undefined
- NaN

Answer (score 0):

"OR" which is used to assign a default value.
An undefined value evaluates to false, hence "OR"ing it with a value returns the value, and that gets assigned to the variable.

```
function myNameFunction(theName)
{
   var theName = theName || "John";
   alert("Hello " + theName);
}

myNameFunction("dhruv")  // alerts "Hello dhruv"
myNameFunction()   // alerts "Hello John"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's for given a default value, and the notation is called OR, as you know it from if statements etc:

Consider this scenario:

```
var Person = function(age){
     this.age = age;
}
console.log(new Person(20).age);
// Output will be 20.

console.log(new Person().age);
// Output will be undefined.
```

If you didn't give an age, the output would be `undefined`.

You can set a default value, if the value you want supplied doesn't exist.

```
var Person = function(age){
     this.age = age || 0;
}
console.log(new Person(20).age);
// Output will be 20.

console.log(new Person().age);
// Output will be 0.
```

To know more about when it applies, see @soulchecks answer.